# How can StringBuilder read more than 16 empty elements?

Tags: java, stringbuilder

Here is my code:

```
   public class Stringclass
   {
   public static void main(String args[])
   {

   StringBuilder s=new StringBuilder();
    s.append("v g f j v n x jc kn vd df jdf jkd kfd kfk dfkd lkd fmk dkkdfd kfdkfn kdfd end");


  System.out.println(s);
   }
   }
```

and output is

```
    v g f j v n x jc kn vd df jdf jkd kfd kfk dfkd lkd fmk dkkdfd kfdkfn kdfd end
```

According to [Java docs] (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/buffers.html) String builder can store only 16 empty characters,So How i am able to get all the characters as a output.

If I write this code then also output is same:

```
    public class Stringclass
    {
    public static void main(String args[])
    {

    StringBuilder s=new StringBuilder("v g f j v n x jc kn vd df jdf jkd kfd kfk dfkd lkd fmk dkkdfd kfdkfn kdfd end");



    System.out.println(s);
     }
     }
```

Comment: What on earth is an "empty character" supposed to be?

Comment: @Ingo I thought may be it takes 16 blocks seperated by white spaces just experimenting a bit.

Answer (score 6):

You misread that. The documentation speaks of the initial **capacity**. By "space", you should read "empty cell where you can put a character".

The underlying array storing the characters has a given initial size (capacity) whose default is 16 and it grows automatically when needed.

Answer (score 2):

Learn the line in the [**Doc**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/buffers.html)

> The capacity, which is returned by the capacity() method, is always greater than or equal to the length (usually greater than) and will automatically expand as necessary to accommodate additions to the string builder.

Answer (score 1):

According to the document you linked:

> A number of operations (for example, `append()`, `insert()`, or `setLength()`) can increase the length of the character sequence in the string builder so that the resultant `length()` would be greater than the current `capacity()`. When this happens, the capacity is automatically increased.